# Driver for Validity sensor 138a:0018

Tags: linux-mint

Does anyone know a driver which supports Validity sensor in HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook? I'm running Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon. If there isn't any driver, can I run the Windows version of the driver for it on Wine? This is the `lsusb` output.

```
chinmaya@chinmaya-HP-dv6 ~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b252 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0018 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint scanner
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please provide a link that explains what "Validity sensor" is. Also include the actual `lsusb` output shoeing the device.

Comment: Whoops. A validity sensor is a fingerprint reader. It came with the laptop.

Comment: There's a possible workaround [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/827669)

Comment: I downloaded the fprint-vfs5011-master.zip file from the github link. Can you please help me compile it?

Comment: Please post a new question explaining any issues you have compiling ( I don't know _what_ you're compiling, there were various workarounds listed on the page I gave you). Anyway, on the SE sites, we don't work like forums, we want specific questions with specific answers. For follow up, post a new question.